# prevent user from changing device's volume

Tags: android

In my android application I want to prevent the volume from changing, means the user should not be able to change the volume of device even if application is not running. Please tell how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)){
            //Nothing
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP: //your code 
               return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN: //your code 
            return true;
        default:
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    }
```